# State of OCFS2 as KVM storage for QCOW2 format

Tags: kvm-virtualization, iscsi, qcow2, ocfs2

Using a shared iSCSI SAN all SSD and good cluster aware filesystems are few and far between with Linux. What is the state of OCFS2 with modern Linux kernels and is it considered reliable enough to have 32 machines sharing the same volume in production? This would be purely VM image storage using QCOW2 so mostly large files.

(or their alternatives for production environment)

Comment: What do you mean by "good cluster aware filesystems"? What constitutes "reliable enough"?

Comment: Although I have limited experience with some, ones that come to mind are GFS and OCFS2. Reliability to us would be a cluster file system that can operate under high load without falling over or going corrupt. For example Windows CSV (cluster shared volume) and VMware VMFS are excellent examples but not designed for Linux KVM hosts as such.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems). You can surely try the more likely ones that have the functionality you need and throw some test loads at them.